# Groupby and perform row-wise calculation using a custom function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Following on from this question: [python - Group by and add new row which is calculation of other rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446863/python-group-by-and-add-new-row-which-is-calculation-of-other-rows/46447447#)

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
col_1   col_2   col_3  col_4
a       X        5      1
a       Y        3      2
a       Z        6      4
b       X        7      8
b       Y        4      3
b       Z        6      5
```

And I want to, for each value in col_1, apply a function with the values in col_3 and col_4 (and many more columns) that correspond to X and Z from col_2 and create a new row with these values. So the output would be as below:

```
col_1   col_2   col_3  col_4 
a       X        5      1
a       Y        3      2
a       Z        6      4
a       NEW      *      *
b       X        7      8
b       Y        4      3
b       Z        6      5
b       NEW      *      *
```

Where `*` are the outputs of the function.

Original question (which only requires a simple addition) was answered with:

```
new = df[df.col_2.isin(['X', 'Z'])]\
  .groupby(['col_1'], as_index=False).sum()\
  .assign(col_2='NEW')

df = pd.concat([df, new]).sort_values('col_1')
```

I'm now looking for a way to use a custom function, such as `(X/Y)` or `((X+Y)*2)`, rather than `X+Y`. How can I modify this code to work with my new requirements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - Group by and add new row which is calculation of other rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446863/python-group-by-and-add-new-row-which-is-calculation-of-other-rows)

Comment: Before seeing coldspeed's answer I had the solution you were looking for.

Comment: Not a duplicate @zipa, it's a follow on from that question. Coldspeed, who answered that question, suggested creating a new question for the added bit of difficulty.

Comment: @Saturate Modified your question for clarity.

Comment: Answer was pretty long, so I'm glad you asked a follow up question. :-)

Comment: Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, that's a lot clearer (but you've answered it now anyway!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here goes:

```
def f(x):
    y = x.values
    return y[0] / y[1] # replace with your function
```

And, the change to `new` is:

```
new = (
    df[df.col_2.isin(['X', 'Z'])]
      .groupby(['col_1'], as_index=False)[['col_3', 'col_4']]
      .agg(f)
      .assign(col_2='NEW')
)

  col_1     col_3  col_4 col_2
0     a  0.833333   0.25   NEW
1     b  1.166667   1.60   NEW

df = pd.concat([df, new]).sort_values('col_1')

df
  col_1 col_2     col_3  col_4
0     a     X  5.000000   1.00
1     a     Y  3.000000   2.00
2     a     Z  6.000000   4.00
0     a   NEW  0.833333   0.25
3     b     X  7.000000   8.00
4     b     Y  4.000000   3.00
5     b     Z  6.000000   5.00
1     b   NEW  1.166667   1.60
```

I'm taking a leap of faith in `f` and assuming those columns are sorted before they hit the function. If this isn't the case, an additional `sort_values` call is needed:

```
df = df.sort_values(['col_1, 'col_2'])
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: This is great. ; I knew you would come up with this.

Comment: @Bharathshetty yeah.. your original answer was okay, but did not address OP's new requirements :-)

Comment: Now you know why it was removed haha.

Comment: Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, that was great again! I just had to change the ['col_3', 'col_4'] part to be a list of all columns apart from col_1 and col_2 as the number of columns to calculate over could change each time, but I can deal with that. All working now anyway, cheers.

Comment: @Saturate It should be easier to instead do `[df.columns.difference(['col_1, 'col_2'])]` instead of `['col_3', 'col_4', xxxxxxx, yyyyyy, zzzzz, aaaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, ....]`. Cheers.

Comment: I've used a list of columns I already have created from another section for this, as col_1 and col_2 could also change, depending on user input. But it's good to know that .difference() is a thing now, so thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
def foo(df):
    # Expand variables into dictionary.
    d = {v: df.loc[df['col_2'] == v, ['col_3', 'col_4']] for v in df['col_2'].unique()}

    # Example function: (X + Y ) * 2
    result = (d['X'].values + d['Y'].values) * 2

    # Convert result to a new dataframe row.
    result = result.tolist()[0]
    df_new = pd.DataFrame(
        {'col_1': [df['col_1'].iat[0]], 
         'col_2': ['NEW'], 
         'col_3': result[0],
         'col_4': result[1]})
    # Concatenate result with original dataframe for group and return.
    return pd.concat([df, df_new])

>>> df.groupby('col_1').apply(lambda x: foo(x)).reset_index(drop=True)
  col_1 col_2  col_3  col_4
0     a     X      5      1
1     a     Y      3      2
2     a     Z      6      4
3     a   NEW     16      6
4     b     X      7      8
5     b     Y      4      3
6     b     Z      6      5
7     b   NEW     22     22
```

Answer (score 0):

A newer approach (which should offer performance advantages) would be to use PyArrow and pandas_udf to support vectorized operations, as documented in Spark 2.4: [PySpark Usage Guide for Pandas with Apache Arrow](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html)