# Group by at Row level in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm a newbie to Python-Pandas.
I've sample dataset like

```
PRODUCT REGION  COUNTRY MEASURE     Month_ID     QTY
P1      West    UK      M1          Mon_1        200
P1      West    UK      M2          Mon_1        150
P1      East    JAPAN   M1          Mon_1        100
P1      East    JAPAN   M2          Mon_1        100
P1      West    UK      M1          Mon_2        300
P1      West    UK      M2          Mon_2        450
P1      East    JAPAN   M1          Mon_2        500
P1      East    JAPAN   M2          Mon_2        600
```

I want data as below:

```
PRODUCT REGION  COUNTRY MEASURE     Month_ID     QTY
P1      West    UK      M1          Mon_1        200
P1      West    UK      M2          Mon_1        150
P1      West    UK      NEW_M       Mon_1        350
P1      East    JAPAN   M1          Mon_1        100
P1      East    JAPAN   M2          Mon_1        100
P1      East    JAPAN   NEW_M       Mon_1        200
P1      West    UK      M1          Mon_2        300
P1      West    UK      M2          Mon_2        450
P1      West    UK      NEW_M       Mon_2        750
P1      East    JAPAN   M1          Mon_2        500
P1      East    JAPAN   M2          Mon_2        600
P1      East    JAPAN   NEW_M       Mon_2        1100
```

I want to group by columns `(PRODUCT, REGION, COUNTRY, Month_ID)` with `SUM(QTY)`.

And new rows will be added after each group with column `MEASURE` as `NEW_M`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert rows as a result of a groupby operation into the original dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446863/insert-rows-as-a-result-of-a-groupby-operation-into-the-original-dataframe)

Comment: Yes, It's a duplicate (similar kind of) of above.

Comment: hmmm, maybe you can add second reqirement for possible reopen question, because no duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new DataFrame by aggregate `sum`, then for correct sorting is added last duplicated index with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), so after [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) add [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for new rows after each group:

```
cols = ['PRODUCT', 'REGION', 'COUNTRY', 'Month_ID']
idx = df.index[df.duplicated(cols)]
df1 = (df.groupby(cols, as_index=False, sort=False)['QTY']
         .sum()
         .assign(MEASURE = 'NEW_M')
         .set_index(idx))

df = pd.concat([df, df1], sort=False).sort_index(kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   PRODUCT REGION COUNTRY MEASURE Month_ID   QTY
0       P1   West      UK      M1    Mon_1   200
1       P1   West      UK      M2    Mon_1   150
2       P1   West      UK   NEW_M    Mon_1   350
3       P1   East   JAPAN      M1    Mon_1   100
4       P1   East   JAPAN      M2    Mon_1   100
5       P1   East   JAPAN   NEW_M    Mon_1   200
6       P1   West      UK      M1    Mon_2   300
7       P1   West      UK      M2    Mon_2   450
8       P1   West      UK   NEW_M    Mon_2   750
9       P1   East   JAPAN      M1    Mon_2   500
10      P1   East   JAPAN      M2    Mon_2   600
11      P1   East   JAPAN   NEW_M    Mon_2  1100
```

EDIT: For subtract is used small trick - values of `QTY` with `M2` in `MEASURE` are multiple by `-1`, so if aggregate `sum` get difference:

```
#if need only `M1` and `M2` rows
df = df[df['MEASURE'].isin(['M1','M2'])]
cols = ['PRODUCT', 'REGION', 'COUNTRY', 'Month_ID']
idx = df.index[df.duplicated(cols)]

df1 = (df.assign(QTY=df['QTY'].mask(df['MEASURE'].eq('M2'),df['QTY'] * -1))
          .groupby(cols, as_index=False, sort=False)['QTY']
         .sum()
         .assign(MEASURE = 'NEW_M')
         .set_index(idx)
         )

df2 = pd.concat([df, df1], sort=False).sort_index(kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
   PRODUCT REGION COUNTRY MEASURE Month_ID  QTY
0       P1   West      UK      M1    Mon_1  200
1       P1   West      UK      M2    Mon_1  150
2       P1   West      UK   NEW_M    Mon_1   50
3       P1   East   JAPAN      M1    Mon_1  100
4       P1   East   JAPAN      M2    Mon_1  100
5       P1   East   JAPAN   NEW_M    Mon_1    0
6       P1   West      UK      M1    Mon_2  300
7       P1   West      UK      M2    Mon_2  450
8       P1   West      UK   NEW_M    Mon_2 -150
9       P1   East   JAPAN      M1    Mon_2  500
10      P1   East   JAPAN      M2    Mon_2  600
11      P1   East   JAPAN   NEW_M    Mon_2 -100
```

Comment: Thank you. One more clarification, if I need to subtract from (M1-M2) instead of SUM(M1+M2), then what'll be the procedure ? Assume M1 may not be always grater than M2. In such case, 3rd row will be ` P1   West      UK   NEW_M    Mon_1   50`

Comment: @TempExpt - there is always only `M1` and `M2` per group?

Comment: No that's not mandatory. But we can filter any 2 MEASUREs as M1 & M2. And I must filter for any 2.

Comment: @TempExpt - Can you check edited answer?